# Why does Cyan appear bluish rather than greenish, when the phototopic eye sensitivity is highest in green (and Cyan contains blue and green equally)?

Tags: vision, eyes, human-eye, color

Cyan contains blue and green equally.

Phototopic eye sensitivity is [highest in green](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-Relationship-Between-Eye-Sensitivity-and-Colour-Wavelength-and-Colour-Luminosity_fig4_269300186).

Why, then, does Cyan appear bluish to most of us, rather than greenish?